# Is it possible to leverage an ArrayList as a session scoped component - ModelAttribute - rather than creating a pojo?

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc

Is it possible to leverage an **ArrayList** or **HashMap** as a "session scoped component" (i.e., ModelAttribute object) - rather than creating a pojo?

If possible, I'd like to create a session scoped modelattribute like  - e.g.,  `"ArrayList<MyPojo>"` or `"HashMap<String, MyPojo>"` -  to share among different controllers.

But, the only examples of modelattribute components I've seen are POJO classes annotated with **"@component"**  and **"@Scope(value="session")**...etc.

Thanks for any guidance on this.

sd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a ModelMap as the command bean and set the ModelMap as a session attribute.

```
@SessionAttributes("testform")
public class testController{
    public ModelAndView testmethod(@ModelAttribute("testform")  ModelMap testMap,HttpServletRequest request){
     /*
      Access form variable using ModelMap.
    */
    }
}
```

** Edit to Send ArrayList **** 
I am not sure if you can do HashMap, but you can definitely do Array of MyPojo i.e MyPojo[]. Please find the JSP and controller below where I have added an hidden type input html element.Code below assumes that your MyPojo class has a member named selected. Hope this helps.

```
<%@taglib uri="/spring.tld" prefix="spring"%>
<spring:bind path="MyPojo[${statusInd.index}].selected">
input type="hidden"
   name='<c:out value="${status.expression}"/>'
   id='<c:out value="${status.expression}" />'
  value='<c:out value="${status.value}" />' />                                  
</spring:bind>      

@SessionAttributes("testform")
public class testController{
    public ModelAndView testmethod(@ModelAttribute("testform")  MyPojo[] testMyPojo,HttpServletRequest request){
     /*
      Access form variable using ModelMap.
    */
    }
}
```

P:S :- You need to tell your JSP that testform is the name of the command Bean for this to work.

Comment: Hi Arun - thanks for your response.   Just to clarify,  I would store objects like "ArrayList<MyPojo>" or "HashMap<String, MyPojo>" within "testMap" (in your example), to share among controllers.   Is this correct?

Comment: Well, I havent heard from you, but, your explanation makes sense. --Unfortunately, I have to wait a while to implement/test. But, I dont want to leave you hanging.  --In any case, thanks again for your help Arun.

Comment: Just checked SO now and saw your comment. I have edited the answer to send MyPojo[] array. I have not tested this code so you might get errors.